# GPU Artifacts on Android app

Tags: android, gpu

I've an app which have a very strange problem. Sometimes when launching the app all the fragments suffer this issue. It looks like the GPU is doing something fancy with it.
In the animated Gif below you can clearly see a PreferenceFragment which has the above mentioned artifacts.

**Edit 1**. it looks like i've a specific fragment that once "draws" on screen the bug appears. Switching fragment using `.replace` won't actually "clean" the problem.

How can i debug this?

[image: gpu-artifacts android]

Comment: is it possible that you have enabled one of that fancy checkboxes in Settings -> Developer options ?

Comment: Hey @Blackbelt I just checked. I had only strictmode active. :( Disabling it didn't have any effect.

Comment: Does it do this on other devices/emulators?

Comment: @LukeStoneHm yes. Tested on  a Nexus 4 api 23 w/ Gapis. same issue!

Comment: I had something similiar happen once, and calling `setRetainInstance(true);` in the fragment solved it. I have no idea what was happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my problem was caused because I had within my theme

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/dark</color>
```

where `dark` is a color item set to `#313131`

Then i had a view that I used as a cover over some other piece of content to darken the underlying views as follow:

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/mydrawable"
            />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/coverview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/dark"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Programmatically I had to set the alpha of the coverview by using `coverView.getBackground().setAlpha((int)(0.6f*255));`

<s>Surprisingly this new alpha value was also applied to the window background and generated a lot of artifacts you see in my question (even after switching fragment where the coverview was no longer in the view tree)</s>

By default, all drawables instances loaded from the same resource share a common state. Hence my code was wrong and i needed to call [.mutate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#mutate()) on the background before applying the new alpha value.

<s>Except for me being wrong @ calling `.setAlpha` without calling `.mutate()` the GPU flickering is still a mistery to me</s>.

Why the GPU Flickers then? As pointed out by Christophe [here](https://plus.google.com/+AndreaBaccega/posts/3FhGfMGteJH):

> the GPU flickers cause the background is now translucent and the
>   system tries to blend it with what was currently in the empty buffer
>   (mostly garbage).

To showcase the <s>bug</s> problem I created a github repo with a sample project showcasing the issue here: https://github.com/vekexasia/gpuflickering-background-alpha

**Workarounds**: Several. If you like to use the same approach (which also causes overdrawing) you should set the color programmatically and then set the alpha value to it. Like so:
`coverView.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark)));`

A better approach would be to apply a [ColorFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setColorFilter(android.graphics.ColorFilter)) to the ImageView or if you're using `Picasso` use a [Transformation](https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/Transformation.html)

Another approach would be to just call `.mutate()` before `.setAlpha()`

Comment: Try: `coverView.getBackground().mutate().setAlpha((int)(0.6f*255));`

Comment: @BladeCoder .mutate() also solves the issue. So the drawables loaded from a resource share a _common state_ and if you want to change only one of them you'll better call `.mutate()` first as you suggested. It just remains to understand why the GPU flickers.

Comment: I'm sorry @BladeCoder I didn't know you were the same guy from G+. I already mentioned you in the last edit of the answer. (I hope you don't mind)

Answer (score 0):

it looks like garbage coming from the GPU.
The first thing you need to look at is your window background (and after that, the various fullscreen layouts backgrounds).
It is probably defined as null or another similar issue.

Comment: The windowBackground is defined in my theme referencing a color resource that resolves to #313131

Comment: The issue came from the window background not being opaque as required, so it was mixed up with the garbage initially present in the GPU hardware buffer when nothing has been drawn yet for the current frame.